# What am i doing wrong in the following code?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>

<h1>MB calculator</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

var level = "0"; var brawlpoints = "0"; var brawlenergy = "0"; var pointsmake = "0";

function setlv()
{
level = docuent.forms["form"]["lv"].value;
alert("level = " + level);
}

var maxen = 95+(lv*5);
var exptolv = 110+(lv*15);

function setbpbe()
{
brawlpoints = document.forms["form"]["bp"].value;
brawlenergy = document.forms["form"]["be"].value;
alert("points per brawl = " + brawlpoints + "; energy per brawl = " brawlenergy);
}

function pointsupdate()
{
pointsmake = document.forms["form"]["p2m"].value;
alert("you want to make " + pointsmake);
}

function calculate()
{
var math1 = pointsmake/brawlpoints + 1;
var math2 = brawlenergy*math1;
var math3 = maxen*1.75;
var math4 = math2/math3 + 1;

document.write("To achieve your goal it will take you " + math1 + " brawls, this will take you " + math2 + " energy, or " + math4 + " levels, assuming a 75% refill levels you.);
}

</script>

<form name="form">

level:
<input type="text" name="lv" value="0">
<br>
<input type="button" value="update level" onclick="setlv()"> 
<br>
points per brawl done:
<input type="text" name="bp" value="0">
<br>
energy per brawl done:
<input type="text name="be" value="0">
<br>
<input type="button" value="update brawl energy and points" onclick="setbpbe()">
<br>
how many points you want to make:
<input type="text" name="p2m" value="0">
<br>
<input type="button" value="set points you want to make" onclick="pointsupdate()">
</form>

<input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()">

<h1>LV calculator</h1>

</html>
```

I looked through it a few times and i can't tell what i am doing wrong...
Sorry for posting the whole thing but i couldn't even really narrow down where the error is, i checked it up against a similar code i have that works fine, i couldn't find a difference other then names which i was consistent with... the buttons are what aren't working. Thanks for any help.

Javascript Output Console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined test.html:64
Uncaught ReferenceError: pointsupdate is not defined test.html:61
Uncaught ReferenceError: setbpbe is not defined test.html:56
Uncaught ReferenceError: setlv is not defined test.html
```

javascript output console while clicking each button

Comment: Have you looked at the output to the javascript console?

Comment: Describe the problem, like what is the result you are getting as opposed to the result you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing lots of things: like

```
// lv is not defined anywhere before using here
var maxen = 95+(lv*5);
var exptolv = 110+(lv*15);
```

missing concat operator here

```
alert("points per brawl = " + brawlpoints + "; energy per brawl = " brawlenergy);
```

should be

```
alert("points per brawl = " + brawlpoints + "; energy per brawl = " + brawlenergy);
```

missing closing quote here

```
document.write("To achieve your goal it will take you " + math1 + " brawls, this will take you " + math2 + " energy, or " + math4 + " levels, assuming a 75% refill levels you.);
```

should be

```
document.write("To achieve your goal it will take you " + math1 + " brawls, this will take you " + math2 + " energy, or " + math4 + " levels, assuming a 75% refill levels you.");
```

**and lots more**..
Make habit of using javascript console so that you know where you went wrong with your code..

Comment: I think it was the lv as opposed to typing level as i intended that made no buttons work...

Comment: Ok, also what is javascript console and why does my post say my functions are undefined?

Answer (score 1):

One spelling mistake is there, instead of document, you typed docuent. May be it's causing errors.

Comment: Thanks, i finally found where you were talking about and fixed that.